# Why does python delete values in lists

Tags: python, list

I have a simple code here and I am unsure as to what it is doing, please care to explain. :)

```
data = [5,6,7,8]

useList = data

useList.pop()
print(useList)
print(data)
```

For some reason the output is:

```
[5, 6, 7]
[5, 6, 7]
```

I do not understand why this occurs because I do not get rid of the 'data' value, I am only wanting to get rid of the useList value.

Is there a way to fix this?

Best Regards and any help will be openly accepted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `useList = data` you simply create another pointer to the same memory of data.

You need to create copy of `data` and that's done like this

```
useList = list(data)
```

Or

```
import copy
useList = copy.copy(data)
```

Comment: Oh, I see! How can I avoid this bug? I only want to delete the value of useList not data @HasanRamezani

Comment: There is no need to import a module to create a shallow copy of a list, `old_list[:]` or `list(old_list)` is sufficient

Comment: Thank you @PadraicCunningham I think I will use your method instead, it looks cleaner too.